# Dojo - How to set "label" of togglebutton inside a grid from row.data.SOMEFIELD value?

Tags: dojo, togglebutton, dgrid

i'm new to Dojo.
I have a "FullEditable" grid, with many columns, and one of them is a widget, it's a ToggleButton. This grid is used to show details of a purchase, so every line represents a product sold. When i click a button inside one of the columns it launches the product (dialog) browser and then the data of that product is passed to the grid. After some work i managed to display the button and being able to set it's label accordingly to the row.data.FIELD value received from that dialog.

But now i am editing that purchase and i need to be able to do the same, to be able to load the data from the preloaded array with data ("detalle") (as it's label) into the togglebutton, but nothing seems to work, not even the direct assignment of the widget or the row data or anything. 
Here's a fragment of my code:

```
  var grid = this;
  var selectedRow = grid.row(i);
  var cell = grid.cell(selectedRow, 'Moneda');
  selectedRow.Moneda = detalle.MonedaItem; //didn't work
  if(cell.row !== null && cell.row !== undefined && cell.row.data !== null && cell.row.data !== undefined)
    cell.row.data.Moneda = detalle.MonedaItem; //didn't work


    if(cell.element !== null && cell.element !== undefined){
      cell.element.innerText = detalle.MonedaItem; //didn't work
      cell.element.textContent = detalle.MonedaItem; //didn't work

      if(detalle.MonedaItem === 'UF')
        cell.element.widget.set('checked', true);
      if(detalle.MonedaItem === 'CLP')
        cell.element.widget.set('checked', false);

      cell.element.widget.set('label', detalle.MonedaItem); //didn't work
      cell.element.widget.set('value', detalle.MonedaItem); //didn't work
    }
  }
```

Whenever i set the value through the change event with "cell.element.widget.set('checked', boolean);" i get an error message from the editor, when it tries to get a cell but the variable is null, so it crashes.

The values of "label" and "value" of the widget, row.data en cell are perfectly set, BUT the grid DISPLAYS the "emptyValue" value of the widget and not the one that is actually set.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, best way to change the grid data is to update the store/ collection that is associated with the grid and just invoke `grid.refresh()`. The new data will be loaded automatically.

The statement `cell.row.data.Moneda = detalle.MonedaItem` is actually changing the data in your store. Just `refresh` the grid after this and you are done!

Never try to set something in grid DOM element directly. Always work with store, `renderCell` and `renderColumn`. This will ensure consistency in store and grid attributes that reference the store.

Comment: After the code i shared comes the grid.refresh(), which does nothing at all visually. As i said, the data, the collection, the cell, and the widget get the right values, BUT after setting the value on the editor.js file, return "this", but "this" has the "wrong" value on its label.  So i added another function to set the value again through cell.row.data.Moneda but then the change triggers again the function on the editor.js and then again the value is overwritten. I know i shouldn't try and do the atrocity of assigning values through dom, but even that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried changing value directly in your store and then calling `refresh` on the grid?

Comment: yes, even though the value is correct in the store and in the collection object

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get what i need through renderCell like this:

```
,{
      id: 'Moneda', 
      field: 'Moneda',
      label: "Moneda",
        renderCell: function (object, value, node, options) {
          try {
            var button = new ToggleButton({
              node: node,
              isWidgetInGrid: true,
              parameterName: 'codigoMoneda',
              label: object.Moneda,
              showLabel: true,
              onChange: function(newValue){
                var grid = this.getParent();
                var row = grid.row(this.node);
                var data = row.data;
                if(this.get('label') === 'CLP')
                {
                  data.Moneda = 'UF';
                  this.set('label','UF');
                  this.set('value', 'UF');
                }
                else
                {
                  data.Moneda = 'CLP';
                  this.set('label','CLP');
                  this.set('value', 'CLP');
                }
                grid.getParent().getParent()._calcularTotales();
              }
            });

            node.appendChild(button.domNode);
          }
          catch (ex) {
            Debug.log(this.declaredClass, arguments, ex);
          }
        },
      emptyValue: 'CLP',
      autoSave: true
    }
```